# R - plotly invisible lines

Tags: r, plotly

I have a data set df which contains variables Name(factor), Count(integer) and Time(POSIXct).

I'm using the following code:

```
    df %>% plot_ly(x=~Time,y = ~Count,group = ~Name,color=~Name,type='scatter',
mode='lines+markers')
```

What happen is that the lines don't appear at all (the markers appear perfectly though). Changing mode to 'lines' makes the data invisible, but the information appear whenever I hover the pointer over data locations.

Also note that running without the groups produce the expected result (with lines visible)

```
        df %>% plot_ly(x=~Time,y = ~Count,type='scatter',
mode='lines+markers')
```

What is wrong? How to make the lines visible?

Comment: could you add some example data to reproduce your problem?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the problem, but found the solution while trying to. The problem was that I used group_by(Time) in an intermediate step so data in different time wouldn't connect I guess. Problem solved by using ungroup(df) before plotting.

Comment: that's the beauty of the minimal reproducible example :) happens to me all the time

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have you tried to ungroup the dataset? It worked for me.

```
df %>% 
   ungroup() %>%
   plot_ly(x=~Time,y = ~Count,type='scatter', mode='lines+markers')
```