# Plotly does not show lines

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, r-plotly

I am using plotly to visualize a dataset into an interactive plot that can be used in a shiny application in a dashboard. I'm using the plotly package as it seems very suitable for me to do something like this. I want to create a plot with lines and markers. When trying to do with a trace using the code below I only get markers and no lines in between

```
plot_ly(cube_eduexpgdp, x = ~year) %>% 
  add_trace(y = ~expenditure_gdp, mode = "lines+markers",
            color = ~country_name, line = list(shape = "linear")) %>%
  layout(title = "Government expenditures as percentage of GDP", 
          yaxis = list(title = "Expenditures (%)"), 
          xaxis = list(title = "Year"))
```

This [tutorial from plotly](https://plot.ly/r/line-charts/) suggests to do it with the following code. When I use this code I get an empty canvas that does show the grouped datapoints' values on a tooltip when I hover over it.

```
plot_ly(cube_eduexpgdp, x = ~year, y = ~expenditure_gdp, 
        color = ~country_name) %>%
  add_lines()  `
```

Is there anyone that could help me? Would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without a reproducible example, I can only guess here, but it is probably due to inheritance and/or `plotly` defaults. Does the code below help?

```
plot_ly(cube_eduexpgdp, x = ~year, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers') %>% 
  add_trace(y = cube_eduexpgdp[['expenditure_gdp']], mode = "lines+markers",
            color = cube_eduexpgdp[['country_name']], line = list(shape = "linear"), inherit = FALSE) %>%
  layout(title = "Government expenditures as percentage of GDP", 
          yaxis = list(title = "Expenditures (%)"), 
          xaxis = list(title = "Year"))
```

Answer (score 16):

I had the same error and found it was caused by trying to plot a grouped dataframe, so had to `ungroup()` first. As found here: [R - plotly invisible lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46102483/r-plotly-invisible-lines)

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your add_trace to: mode = 'markers'

I had a similar problem - legend was showing lines+markers correctly but the plot only displaying markers. After troubleshooting, swapping from 'lines+markers' to simply 'markers' actually made the lines appear. The lines did accept the list() arguments provided in the trace as well.

Comment: To clarify: this appears to be a work-around for mode = 'markers'.  When you do this you will receive a warning: "A line object has been specified, but lines is not in the mode.  Adding lines to mode..."  It does, however, get the job done.